# PMBOK 4th Edition - Monitor and Control Project Work versus other Control Processes, what are the differences?

Tags: process, pmbok, contracts

Are there any significant differences between "Monitor and Control Project Work" process versus other control processes e.g., control scope, control schedule, control cost, perform quality control?

From what I understand is that Monitor and Control Project Work which falls under integration knowledge area just ensures all the control process activities are monitored and contolled in an integrated manner. I think all other control processes are sufficient without having Monitor and Control Project Work process, but I am quite confused and am hoping somebody can explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

They are both basically the same thing, for a few reasons.

Monitor & Control Execution is first and foremost a Process Group, not a Process. The 42 Processes fall under the 5 Process Groups. These 5 Groups get repeated during each phase of the project.

The Project Integration Management Knowledge Area of the PMBoK Guide was inserted as a catch-all for the various processes that didn't specifically fall under any one specific Knowledge Area, primarily because they cross all of the Knowledge Area (so M& C couldn't be listed under Cost Mgmt when it aslo applies to Time Mgmt.)

As for the other Process being sufficient without M & C - kind of. They're sufficient in and of themselves in that they can be separated from the others, but they still need to be Monitored & Controlled, hence the Project Integration KA.

And remember, the Process Groups repeat during each phase, and M & C runs the duration of each phase. M & C is what gets you from Initiate to Close.

Comment: Hi Nelson, I've got confused. Because I see process "4.4-Monitor and Control Project Work" is overlap with other M & C process e.g., e.g., control scope, control schedule, control cost, perform quality control?

Comment: Yes. 4.4 reads "execute the work defined in the pm plan to achieve project's requirements defined in the scope statement." This means that M & C (actually 4.4 says Direct and Manage) covers all of the other processes to monitor and ensure they're progressing appropriately.